# Stuck on choose account for application in android

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am using google drive authorization in my application. While I was running the application using android studio debug/run option, it was working fine. But, today I published the application and after installing it, I am stuck at `choose account for appname`. I don't know what wrong happened?

I tried a few options:

1. Since the app package name should not contain .example while uploading apk to google play store, I did the same in my `https://console.developers.google.com/` credentials. This didn't work.
2. Tried to re-install the application, but it didn't work either.

the google drive code is:

```
  private void saveFileToDrive() {
        // Start by creating a new contents, and setting a callback.
        //Log.i(TAG, "Creating new contents.");
        Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {
                        // If the operation was not successful, we cannot do anything
                        // and must
                        // fail.
                        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            //Log.i(TAG, "Failed to create new contents.");
                            return;
                        }
                        // Otherwise, we can write our data to the new contents.
                        //Log.i(TAG, "New contents created.");
                        // Get an output stream for the contents.
                        OutputStream outputStream = result.getDriveContents().getOutputStream();
                        // Write the bitmap data from it.
                        FileInputStream fis;
                        try {
                            fis = new FileInputStream(outputFile);
                            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                            int n;
                            while (-1 != (n = fis.read(buf)))
                                baos.write(buf, 0, n);
                            byte[] photoBytes = baos.toByteArray();
                            outputStream.write(photoBytes);

                            outputStream.close();
                            fis.close();
                            //Log.w(TAG, "Successfully written: ");
//                            let us delete the file here
                            File file = new File(outputFile);
                            if (file.delete())
                            {
                                //Log.d(TAG, "Successfully deleted.");
                            }


                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            //Log.w(TAG, "FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            //Log.w(TAG, "Unable to write file contents." + e1.getMessage());
                        }
                        // Create the initial metadata - MIME type and title.
                        // Note that the user will be able to change the title later.
                        MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                .setMimeType("audio/mpeg").setTitle(file_name_with_extension).build();
                        // Create an intent for the file chooser, and start it.
                        Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(mGoogleApiClient)
                                .createFile(mGoogleApiClient, metadataChangeSet, result.getDriveContents())
                        ;

                    }
                });
    }


    /**
     * Called before the activity is destroyed
     */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.resume();
        }
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            // Create the API client and bind it to an instance variable.
            // We use this instance as the callback for connection and connection
            // failures.
            // Since no account name is passed, the user is prompted to choose.
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }
        // Connect the client. Once connected, the camera is launched.
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.pause();
        }

        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Store the image data as a bitmap for writing later.
            //Log.d(TAG, "Data is saved successfully.");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The file " + file_name + " has been saved successfully to your drive.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
        //Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            // show the localized error dialog.
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, result.getErrorCode(), 0).show();
            return;
        }
        // The failure has a resolution. Resolve it.
        // Called typically when the app is not yet authorized, and an
        // authorization
        // dialog is displayed to the user.
        try {
            result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        //Log.i(TAG, "API client connected.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        //Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
    }
```

My app is live here:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.khan.spyrecorder

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Is the issue more related on the Account Picker when connecting to Google API (consent screen)? Have you tried using the [AccountPicker](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/AccountPicker) class? I think this can help you with the issue.

Comment: yes, it is related to the consent screen. It is very frustrating. Earlier, everything was working fine.